# How Do I Find Duplicates For Multiple Column Combinations in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose I have a table *emp* with the following data

| Id | first_name | last_name | age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | 20 |
| 2 | Jane | Smith | 90 |
| 3 | John | Doe | 39 |
| 4 | Jane | Smith | 47 |
| 5 | Jane | Doe | 89 |

I want a query that returns *first_name*, *last_name* duplicate combos i.e.

| Id | first_name | last_name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | Doe | 20 |
| 3 | John | Doe | 39 |
| 2 | Jane | Smith | 90 |
| 4 | Jane | Smith | 47 |

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Oracle: find duplicate rows in select query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13776123/1509264) and [Finding duplicate values in table (and getting their pk's)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18128917/1509264)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems you simply need a `COUNT() OVER()` window function -

```
SELECT ROWNUM, first_name, last_name, age
  FROM (SELECT first_name, last_name, age, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY first_name, last_name) CNT
          FROM Your_table)
 WHERE CNT > 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one option.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with emp (id, first_name, last_name, age) as
  2    (select 1, 'John', 'Doe'  , 20 from dual union all
  3     select 2, 'Jane', 'Smith', 90 from dual union all
  4     select 3, 'John', 'Doe'  , 39 from dual union all
  5     select 4, 'Jane', 'Smith', 47 from dual union all
  6     select 5, 'Jane', 'Doe'  , 89 from dual
  7    )
```

Query begins here:

```
  8  select *
  9  from emp
 10  where (first_name, last_name) in (select first_name, last_name
 11                                    from emp
 12                                    group by first_name, last_name
 13                                    having count(*) > 1
 14                                   )
 15  order by first_name, last_name;

        ID FIRS LAST_        AGE
---------- ---- ----- ----------
         4 Jane Smith         47
         2 Jane Smith         90
         3 John Doe           39
         1 John Doe           20

SQL>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
SELECT 
    Id, first_name, last_name, age,
    COUNT(*)
FROM 
    EMP
GROUP BY 
    ID,
    first_name,
    last_name, 
    age;
```

thank you!

Comment: This answer will not produce the expected result.

Comment: it shows the duplicated values count at least.

Comment: No, it does not. It will show all 5 rows and they will each have a count of `1`.